# How to pass java object to groovy method that being called in java?

Tags: java, groovy

I'm calling groovy method that take one POJO from java but getting exception.

Here is detail:

File: SampleScript2.groovy

```
import com.hrishikeshmishra.sb.Obj;

class SampleScript2 {

    String process(Obj obj) {
        if(obj.num ==10)
            return "equal";
        else
            return "not-equal"
    }
}
```

File: com/hrishikeshmishra/sb/Obj.java

```
package com.hrishikeshmishra.sb;

class Obj {
    public int num;

    public Obj(int num) {
        this.num = num;
    }
}
```

File: com/hrishikeshmishra/sb/JavaGroovyTest.java

```
package com.hrishikeshmishra.sb;

import groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader;
import groovy.lang.GroovyObject;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;


public class JavaGroovyTest {

    static final GroovyClassLoader classLoader = new GroovyClassLoader();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IllegalAccessException, IOException, InstantiationException {
        example6();
    }

    private static void example6() throws IOException, IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {

        Class groovy = classLoader.parseClass(new File("/Users/hrishikesh.mishra/hrishi/codes/sb/groovyjava/src/main/resources/SampleScript2.groovy"));
        GroovyObject groovyObj = (GroovyObject) groovy.newInstance();
        String output = (String) groovyObj.invokeMethod("scriptSays", new Object[] { new Obj(12)});
        System.out.println(output);
    }
}
```

**Exception:**

```
Exception in thread "main" org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MissingMethodExceptionNoStack: No signature of method: SampleScript2.scriptSays() is applicable for argument types: (com.hrishikeshmishra.sb.Obj) values: [com.hrishikeshmishra.sb.Obj@51931956]
```

Comment: The error is very explicit: the class in SampleScript2.groovy does not have the method you're trying to invoke: `scriptSays()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're trying to invoke a method called `scriptSays()`, but the method you've defined is actually called `process()`...

Comment: @HrishikeshMishra you're welcome. Do consider marking as accepted answer (click the tick) if it was useful.